# Scraping information from a webpage that has a table spanning many pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm using the `rvest` package in `R` and would like to scrape some data from a table that only includes about 40% of the total information. I followed [this blog](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest) post, but it doesn't specify how to scrape data when there is no difference in the HTML address for the different pages. [This website](http://explore.msujobs.msstate.edu/cw/en-us/filter/?search-keyword=&job-mail-subscribe-privacy=agree&location=main%20campus%20-%20starkville%20ms&category=faculty) is the one I'm trying to obtain some job listing data from.

I've successfully retrieved the data on the first page using this code:

```
job_page <-
  read_html(
    'page_address'
  )

data_raw <- job_page %>%
  html_node('table') %>%
  html_text()
```

Is it possible to scrape the webpage when the HTML address is NOT different for multiple pages of data? My hope is to use `lapply` to iterate over the multiple pages in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this URL instead, it should give you all results in one page:

```
http://explore.msujobs.msstate.edu/cw/en-us/filter/?search-keyword=&job-mail-subscribe-privacy=agree&location=main%20campus%20-%20starkville%20ms&category=faculty&page=1&page-items=100
```

You can open the developer tools in Chrome and select Network tab. You can examine the request and tweak searching parameters.